# show.bs.modal won't fire in externally loaded bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'd like to be able to load a common modal dialog (which is stored in an external file) into any page, which needs a modal as part of the page. It seems to mostly work, except that neither the show.bs.modal or hide.bs.modal events are triggered when the modal markup is loaded from the external file - Yet, the events trigger fine if I comment out the the loading of external html and just copy the external files markup directly into the body of the page.

In the page (index.html), which loads the modal markup and then displays it, I have the following markup.

```
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#simpleModalDialog" >
         open External Modal
    </button>

    <div id="externalModal" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#externalModal').load('modal_dialog_simple.html');
            // setup handlers
            $('#simpleModalDialog').on('show.bs.modal',function(){
                console.log('show bs modal event triggered');
            });
            $('#simpleModalDialog').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
                console.log('hide bs modal event triggered.');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

in the external file, modal_dialog_simple.html, the markup is as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="simpleModalDialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" >
        <div class="modal-content">            
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 id="modal_heading" class="modal-title">
                    Simple Modal Heading
                </h4>
                <button id="modal_close_button" type="button" 
                    class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" value="test" id="message"/>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
                    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the `show.bs.modal` and `hide.bs.modal` event listeners before the modal HTML has been loaded.

Use the callback function on jQuery's [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) method to ensure the modal HTML has been loaded, and then set the event listeners.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#externalModal').load('modal_dialog_simple.html', function() {

        // setup handlers
        $('#simpleModalDialog').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
            console.log('show bs modal event triggered');
        });
        $('#simpleModalDialog').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
            console.log('hide bs modal event triggered.');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> neither the show.bs.modal or hide.bs.modal events are triggered when the modal markup is loaded from the external file

The **simpleModalDialog** is not yet loaded when you attach the event handler. You can use event delegation or the [complete](http://api.jquery.com/load/) jQuery load callback. Using event delegation you can write:

```
$('#externalModal').on('show.bs.modal', '#simpleModalDialog', function(){
      console.log('show bs modal event triggered');
});
$('#externalModal').on('hide.bs.modal', '#simpleModalDialog', function(){
      console.log('hide bs modal event triggered.');
});
```

Another possibility is [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Eventi#Event_bubbling_and_capture) in case of no [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). In this way you can attach the event handler directly to the **externalModal** parent:

```
 $('#externalModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
      console.log('show bs modal event triggered');
});
$('#externalModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
      console.log('hide bs modal event triggered.');
});
```